# WordPress Contact Form 7 ajax loader infinity

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form7

Используется тема Bridge При отправке формы через Contact Form 7 в Google Chrome всё отлично работает. Если какие-то поля не заполнены - пишет ошибку: "Это поле обязательно". Через Safari полностью заполненная форма отправляется, однако же, если в форме не заполнены какие-либо обязательные поля - крутится ajax-loader до бесконечности. Пробовал отключать ajax перезагрузку, но такой вариант не подходит, ибо очень нужна отправка без перезагрузки http://rabotavkazani.ru/rabota-v-kazani/

Comment: У вас там анкета о 120 полях. Вы считаете, что у людей есть время заполнять её? Создайте минимальный пример - отдельную страницу на своём сайте, с одним полем, и дайте ссылку в вопросе. Тогда, возможно, вам помогут.

Comment: Так заполнять ничего не нужно, ошибка как раз происходит, при НЕзаполненных полях

Comment: В Хроме все ок http://take.ms/sQIf8 Или проблема только в Сафари? Из вопроса непонятно.

Comment: Проблема только в Safari  наблюдается
Нашел причину проблемы - input[type="file"]
Если загрузить фото - все отправляется
Иначе вечный ajax loader